# how to add dynamic values to a two dimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have 15 inputs from a view and they are optional to fill up so I need to check if they have values first before I put them to an array. how can I put these 15 values into a multidimensional array? I need to pair them with 3.

```
for(int i=1; i<=10;i++)
{
    if($request->input('time'.i)!=null && $request->input('OT_Date'.i)!=null)
    {
        $Date = array('' => , );
        $num++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show us text samples of the array structures you start and wish to end with, I'm really unsure what your'e asking otherwise sorry.

Comment: Why does the loop go to 10 instead of 15? It doesn't really affect the answer, but you mentioned that there were 15 inputs, so you seem to think the number is important.

Comment: I want to use it like this for output echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";

Comment: `$cars[] = array($carname, $carstock, $carsold);`

Comment: If you need to check whether there's an entry for a car name first, it would be better to make it an associative array.

Comment: oh yeah, i need 15. i'm still new to programming.

Comment: how to make an associative array?

Comment: I GOT IT NOW! thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

**here is how you can add dynamic values in multidimensional array:**

```
$array = array('key1'=>'value1');

$array['new_key'] = 'new_value';
```